# "Not quite yet" vs "not yet"

Tags: phrases

Does the phrase 'not quite yet' mean that something will be done shortly?

Does this imply less time than just 'not yet'?

Comment: I think anybody who's had a mom should know the difference, right?

Comment: See "*quite*"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this sense of "quite" is as used in both UK and US English (see 1st meaning [here for definition](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/quite)), meaning "completely", so that "not quite yet" implies that the task is not completely finished, but also that the majority of the work is done. "Not yet" is simply a more polite way of saying "No" in this case.

So to answer your questions
 1. Yes, it does mean that it will be done shortly.
 2. Yes, it does imply less time than "not yet"

NB: Definition linked above is this:

> quite /kwaɪt/ adv to the greatest extent; completely or absolutely:
>   you're quite right, quite the opposite

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that in some Asian languages, the phrase "Not quite yet" can be said in a single word. It's a way of saying that you could do or learn to do something if you wanted to.

If someone asked you if you can play the guitar and you can't, instead of saying "no" you would say "not quite yet", indicating that you could learn if you wanted to. It's a way of looking at things with a positive attitude.

Answer (score -2):

When some one asks about any task : We simply say : Not yet.

When it has been long time and still the task is pending, we say : Not quite yet..

Comment: I disagree with your second sentence. "quite" in "not quite yet" means "It is not yet done, but is nearing completion." It doesn't have anything to do with how long it's been since the task started or was assigned.

Comment: Yeah, but it could. I think this is a hilarious explanation. "we say not quite yet when we want them to stop asking"